# authenticate user to windows and get windows username

Tags: c#, api, basic-authentication, windows-authentication, credentials

User entering username and password for login in project. But customer want passwordless login with windows authenticated for every employee. I changed authentication mode from anonymous authentication to windows authentication. Now required windows authenticated before the application run.But entering the windows credential same username and password every time, which containing project published in iis.

Question 1. How i do required only client windows username and password in windows authentication?

Assuming i used client windows username and password for authentication. IsAuthenticated = true;

Here my new question.

Question 2. How i do catch client windows username?

Now use 2 different way for catch windows username.

Way 1.

```
var name = _username.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            var isactive = _username.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            return $"name: " + name + " | IsAuthenticated: " + isactive;
```

Return this -> name: URCTEST01\Ziya Mammadov | IsAuthenticated: True

Way 2.

```
            WindowsIdentityHelper wih = new WindowsIdentityHelper();

            var name = wih.GetLoginUserName();

            return name;
```

```
 public class WindowsIdentityHelper
    {
        public WindowsPrincipal GetWindowsPrincipal()
        {
            //Get Current AppDomain
            AppDomain myDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
            myDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            return (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        }

        public bool IsUserBelongsToWindowsAdministratorGroup()
        {
            WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = GetWindowsPrincipal();

            if (myPrincipal.IsInRole("Administrators"))
                return true;

            if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public string GetFullDomainLoginUserName()
        {
            WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = GetWindowsPrincipal();
            return myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString();
        }

        public string GetLoginUserName()
        {
            string authenticatedUser = string.Empty;
            string userName = GetFullDomainLoginUserName();
          
                authenticatedUser = userName;
            return authenticatedUser;
        }
    }
```

Return this -> IIS APPPOOL\timesheet

Way 1 return username which windows contain project.
Way 2 return IIS APPPOOL.

How to catch correct username?

Comment: https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html?m=1

Comment: @WiktorZychla thank for your response. But i don't understanded third case. Others is ok.

Comment: Third doesn't apply for browsers other than ie